# Python - passing a result to a list

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, gurobi

I'm using Python to solve an integer program using Gurobi. After defining all variables and constraints, I'm getting the following answers for my integer variable `x[i,j]`.

```
x(0,0) 0.0
x(0,1) 0.0
x(0,2) 1.0
x(0,3) 1.0
x(1,0) 0.0
x(1,1) 0.0
x(1,2) 0.0
x(1,3) 0.0
x(2,0) 0.0
x(2,1) 0.0
x(2,2) 0.0
x(2,3) 0.0
x(3,0) 0.0
x(3,1) 0.0
x(3,2) 0.0
x(3,3) 0.0
```

So, in the next step, I need to pass all `i,j` s for which `x[i,j]=1` to a set called `S`. I'm using the following code for this.

```
S=[]
if x[i,j]== 1:
  S.append(i)
  S.append(j)
  print(S)
```

This prints `S=[0,3]`. But the correct one should be `S=[0,2,3]`. Can someone please help me to identify the mistake here?

Comment: is it in a forloop?

Comment: and for sets...its much better to use s.add(i) or update(i)

Comment: S is not a set...its a list S=[].. change to S=set()

Comment: Please show your looping construct, e.g. is `S = []` inside the loop, it needs to be outside. And presumable `S = set(); ... S.add(i)`

Comment: Each time you add anything to S, you're adding two things (i and j). So how can S end up with an odd number of elements?

Comment: If the code checks for the presence of the elements (say using index for arrays > -1), then add only those values that are not present. Then the code can have the desired values.
@AChampion Your suggestion should also be incorporated.

Comment: Gurobi FAQ 26? http://www.gurobi.com/support/faqs - try checking `if x[i.j] > 0.5`.

Answer (score 1):

First thing, the code provided is not complete so I can only speculate what you could have done and give suggestions based on it.

I believe that you have written a for loop and in that S = [] is getting initialised all the time.

Thus, your code though almost correct still gives only the last matching solution.

What I would have done would be following:

```
S = []

<here goes code for some for loop to consider all the x[i,j] values>
    if x[i,j] == 1:
        if not S.index[i]>-1:
            S.append[i]
        if not S.index[j]>-1:
            S.append[j]
return S
```

This pseudo-code based program should give you the correct solution :)

Comment: This is not very efficient, better to just use `S = set()` and `s.update((i, j))`. Set's automatically handle duplicate entries. Note: `if i not in S` would be the more appropriate condition.